# Convergence of a series with terms in-between harmonic and geometric

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$, and let $K \in \mathbb N$. Consider the infinite series as a function a $K$:

$$f(K) = \frac{K^\alpha}{(1+K^\alpha)} + \frac{K^\alpha (K+1)^\alpha}{(1+K^\alpha)(1+(K+1)^\alpha)} + \frac{K^\alpha (K+1)^\alpha (K+2)^\alpha}{(1+K^\alpha)(1+(K+1)^\alpha)(1+ (K+2)^\alpha} + \dots $$

My questions are:

1. Is $f(K)$ finite?
2. Is $\lim_{K \to \infty} f(K)$ finite?

Note that when $\alpha = 0$, the series always converges to $1$. When $\alpha = 1$, it always diverges. So the question boils down to: what happens when $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Based on simulations, the answer to 1 is yes, and 2 is no. If fact it seems $f(K) \approx K^{\theta}$ for some $\theta \in (0,1)$ which depends on $\alpha$ in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Assume $K>0$. One may rewrite the given series as
$$
f(K)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\prod_{m=0}^n (K+m)^\alpha}{\prod_{m=0}^n(1+(K+m)^\alpha)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{\prod_{m=0}^n \left(1+\dfrac1{(K+m)^\alpha}\right)}.
$$ Then, as $n \to \infty$, one has
$$
\log\left(\prod_{m=1}^n \left(1+\dfrac1{(K+m)^\alpha}\right)\right)\sim \sum_{m=K+1}^{K+n}\frac1{m^\alpha}\sim\dfrac{(n+K)^{1-\alpha}-(K+1)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}
$$ and the general term of the initial series is
$$
\frac1{\prod_{m=1}^n \left(1+\dfrac1{(K+m)^\alpha}\right)} = \mathcal{O}\left(e^{-\dfrac{n^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}} \right)
$$ thus $f(K)$ is finite.

One may proceed in this way to adress the second point.